# Blur shader without render textures?

Tags: unity, shaders, post-processing

Is it possible to append a blur shader to a standard (diffuse) shader ? I am looking for a way to do this as Unity indie doesn't allow render textures.

Comment: Can't you apply the blurr while rendering everything to screen? Might not be ideal but blending slightly and sampling randomly might give a nice enough effect.

Comment: @RoyT. What do you mean? I can't since I don't have access to render textures.

Comment: But you do have shaders right? I mean trying to blur everything individually while drawing it to screen and making everything slightly transparent so that the blend into each other. Not sure how good it would look though.

Comment: @RoyT. Got the shaders.

Comment: Yes, but it's much worse looking and way slower.  Upgrade your Unity license or use a Freer engine.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, you could use Shader Replacement to re-render your whole scene using shaders that offset the positions of everything slightly, and output with e.g. 25% alpha.

So you'd render the scene normally, and then:

```
Clear depth buffer
Set shader replacement to offset everything 1px left and 25% alpha
Render
Clear depth buffer
Set shader replacement to offset everything 1px right and 25% alpha
Render
Clear depth buffer
Set shader replacement to offset everything 1px up and 25% alpha
Render
Clear depth buffer
Set shader replacement to offset everything 1px down and 25% alpha
Render
```

Or something along those lines, anyway.